# If error on Access query

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Hi I am doing a query in MS Access that is the following:

```
Tenure_days: DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),11)-DateSerial(Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],1,4),Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],6,2),Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],9,2))
```

In some records is get #Error when **[AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date]** is empty, so how do I edit the above query so that when **Tenure_days = #Error** to put **120** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the field is empty, you need to test if the field is empty first. Try this,

```
Tenure_days: IIF(Len([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date] & "") = 0, 120, DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),11) - DateSerial(Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],1,4),Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],6,2),Mid([AHT_Tenure].[ABAY Start Date],9,2)))
```

You first using an **I**mmediate **IF**, see if the field you are using the `Mid` function to is empty or not. If it is empty you are giving 120 straight away. If not, you are performing the operation. I hope this helps.